# Why am I getting this error: No mapping specified for the following EntitySet/AssociationSet - Entity1?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I'm using Entity Framework 4 with the Model First approach.

I started the project, designed the entities and generated the database. Everything worked fine.

Then I needed to go back and add another entity to my model. However, as I drag an entity to the EDMX I get this error:

[image]

Alright! I just need to map Entity1 to a table.. But hey! I'm using Model First approach, I expect it to create the table for me when I generate the DDL.

How do I work around this error?

Comment: So can generate database script from your model?

Comment: [If you are using "Update Model From Database", maybe this post will help you](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40085976/5713106)

Answer (score 160, accepted):

This is because of the way EF4 works with model-first.

When you first create a model-first model, it's in a state that the SSDL does not exist. You can drag entities, associate them and so forth and yet, if you take a look at the SSDL on the EDMX file, you will see that none of the entities have an associated storage table in the SSDL.

That changes when you click the `Generate Database From Model` context menu item. The confusing part is that this action does more than simply generating a DDL script. In fact, it changes the EDMX file to include SSDL information. From this point on, the EDMX file will enter a state in which every entity in the designer/CSDL must map to an entity in the SSDL. If one does not map, it will trigger a compile time error:

> No mapping specified for the following EntitySet/AssociationSet - (EntityName)

Another interesting fact is that it's not the kind of error that will prevent compilation. It will, indeed, generate the output class library. Shouldn't it be a warning or something?

To prevent this error, All you have to do after inserting a new entity is to `Generate Database From Model` again. That will update the SSDL and fix the mappings.

**EDIT**

If you are not using model-first and you "update from database", you will also have this error in the case you deleted a table in DB Server. This is because Entity Framework will not automatically delete the entity for you. Delete the entity manually and the error will go away.

Comment: I got the same issue after updating my model against bd changes (that could not be good, as my approach is not model-first).

Comment: @balanza, when you are not using model-first and you update your model based on database, you will get this error when you delete a table in the server because the EF designer will NOT delete the entity automatically. When you manually delete the entity type, the error will go away

Comment: I changed mine directly in the xml file of the entity data model. I had heaps of tables and functions and there was a risk of some mismatch thus I did it manually.

Comment: This is SUPER helpful. Also, if you are using model-first and "update from database" and get new tables, you will also have the error. But running Generate Database from Model (no need to actually execute the generated script--it'll kill your data!) will fix the mapping issues in your code and you'll have no problem using it going forward.

Comment: How would you handle schema updating for already deployed SQL Server CE database ? Can move this to a separate question, if it's totally unrelated procedure

Comment: "you will also have this error in the case you deleted a table in DB Server":The same will happen even if the object was not deleted but the credentials used by the model had a change on permissions and now there is no access to the object.If that's the case, GRANT permissions on the object to the user account. e.g. If the connection string in the application configuration file has: "user id=TheLoginName; ..." etc. and the associated user is [TheUserName] on the data server, Run this command against the server:

Grant Select (And other operations if necessary) On TheObjectName To TheUserName

Comment: Apologies for reviving this q/a. But i'm seeing the same issue under a different scenario and was wondering if someone could confirm that this is still a solution for me. I have a DB first model generated from the DB which i then modify slightly with some associations not found in the DB. This modifying of the model produces the error listed here. In this scenario would i still need to execute "Generate DB from Model" but do not execute the SQL script in order for it to function properly?

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solved my issue. Much appreciated

Answer (score 37):

I found I was getting the same error because I had forgot to create referential constraint after creating an association between two entities.

Comment: FYI: Check the association's properties, and on the bottom "Referential Constraint" will be empty.  Click the ellipsis and create a constraint.

Comment: This helped me. I had to create a 1..* relationship from my origin entity to my navigational entity.

Answer (score 25):

> Error 3027: No mapping specified for the following EntitySet/AssociationSet ..." - Entity Framework headaches

If you are developing model with Entities Framework then you may run into this annoying error at times:

> Error 3027: No mapping specified for the following EntitySet/AssociationSet [Entity or Association Name]

This may make no sense when everything looks fine on the EDM, but that's because this error has nothing to do with the EDM usually. What it should say is "regenerate your database files".

You see, Entities checks against the SSDL and MSL during build, so if you just changed your EDM but doesn't use **Generate Database Model...** then it complains that there's stuff missing in your sql scripts.

so, in short, the solution is:
"Don't forget to  **Generate Database Model** every time after you update your EDM if you are doing model first development. I hope your problem is solved".

Comment: This worked for this same error doing the Generate Database Model helped clear the exception

Answer (score 8):

I ran into the same error, but I was not using model-first. It turned out that somehow my EDMX file contained a reference to a table even though it did not show up in the designer. Interestingly, when I did a text search for the table name in Visual Studio (2013) the table was not found.

To solve the issue, I used an external editor (Notepad++) to find the reference to the offending table in the EDMX file, and then (carefully) removed all references to the table. I am sorry to say that I do not know how the EDMX file got into this state in the first place.

Answer (score 7):

In my case, another developer had removed some of the tables from the underlying database. When I realised this, and removed these tables from the entity, the problem was solved. Wasn't as obvious as it sounds.

Comment: In my case it was only a column that had been removed from the table but EF update from db didn't realize it and I had to remove that column manually from XML.

Answer (score 5):

I had a table change and it created another entity with a number 1 at the end (such as `MyEntity1` and a `MyEntity`) as confirmed by the edmx model browser. Something about the two entities together confused the processing.

Removal of the table and re-adding it fixed it.

---

*Note that if TFS is hooked up, then do a check-in of the edmx in after the delete. Then and only then get the latest and re-add it in a definite two step process. Otherwise TFS gets confused with the delete and re-add of same named entity(ies) which seems to cause problems.*

Comment: I had the same issue after a table change.  I found the same entities with a number 1 and 2 (MyEntity1, MyEntity2) in several places under the model.  I looked in every branch (Diagrams, Entity Types, etc.) and removed every instance of MyEntity and MyEntity[n].  For good measure I did a "Clean Solution" and then updated from database to re-add only MyEntity.

Answer (score 5):

A quicker way for me was to delete the tables and re-add them. It Auto-mapped them. :)

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to Solution Explorer, click the Search button
2. Leave checked both `Search within file content` and `Search External Files`
3. Type the entities name which your mapping isn't recognizing.
4. Delete all files RELATED to the problem. *Those will probably be named after the same missing entity. DO NOT delete any file with your Context Class name on the file, specially if their extensions are .cs or .tt. In the Context .cs file*.
5. remove all lines of codes referencing the missing entity. They will look like this:

   ```
   public virtual DbSet< Entity1> Entity1 { get; set; }
   ```

This error is common to tables deleted from the database.

When one drops a table in the database, or one just changes the `web.config.connectionStrings` for the EF Mapped database, to point to a new one and not the one used to generate the original mappings is the problem.

It is this new db these entities with the 3027 error aren't present.

Answer (score 2):

For those who are using `Database First` approach all you have to do after inserting a new entity is to `Generate Database From Model` again by right click on your `.edmx` file and select `Generate Database From Model...`

Answer (score 1):

Update Model from Database doesn't works for me.

I had to remove the conflicted entity, then execute Update Model from Database, lastly rebuild the solution. After that, everything works fine.

Comment: This solved it for me. Thank you Thank you

Comment: Glad to hear that!

Answer (score 1):

In my case I found a table named sysdiagram created in the EDMX diagram and not in the production database, so I just deleted it from the model and now everything is working fine.
This table may have been created in the development database and i forgot to delete it so it caused the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Had this error when I had deleted a table from the database. Solved it by right clicking on EDMX diagram, going to Properties, selecting the table from the list in the Properties window, and deleting it (using delete key) from the diagram.

Answer (score 0):

I had the error when I was trying to make a custom result for a stored procedure and assumed it had to be an entity.

The solution was that I just made a complex type in the Model browser and assigned that as a result to the "Edit function imports".

I will add it here since it looks like this question is where google takes you when you get this error.

Answer (score 0):

I had set everything correctly (cardinalities and dependent properties) but could not figure out why I keep receiving error. Finally figured out that, EF generated a column in dependent table on its own (table_tablecolumn) and it does not have any relation to the table, so no mapping was specified. I had to delete the column in EDMX file and rebuild the solution which fixed the issue. I am using DB approach.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing this for other people. In my case, we were working on a shared MVC solution, and using a common module for tables that we use for dropdowns. I got the error when I updated the Entity model by adding a new table. It turns out that when I updated the the EDMX, it probably updated my rights access on the database, which resulted to not having access to that certain table giving me `no mapping specified`.

Just re-adding and giving access to my user solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got this from not explicitly deleting some tables from the edmx before renaming and re-adding them.  Instead, I just renamed the tables and then did an Update Model from Database, thinking it would see them gone, and delete them from model.  I then did another Update Model from Database and added the renamed tables.

The site was working with the new tables, but I had the error.  Eventually, I noticed the original tables were still in the model.  I deleted them from the model (click them in edmx screen, delete key), and then the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using model-first; Double click 'edmx' file ->select all and delete all entity models -> save -> right click 'update model from database ->select required tables ->finish and save.