# How to create a new separate entity in EF 6 and map a stored procedure to it?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6, mapping

I created a new entity myself in EF 6 and I'm getting

> Error 3027: No mapping specified for the following EntitySet/AssociationSet

How do I get rid of it?

I am trying to create a new entity and map a stored procedure to it. The stored procedure has temp tables in it. I want to be able to call that stored procedure and move the resultset to a list.

Comment: Could you provide a better question ? Here are some articles to help us help you. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: Try these? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667355/why-am-i-getting-this-error-no-mapping-specified-for-the-following-entityset-as